# recover from segmentation fault in apache filter

Tags: c, apache, filter, segmentation-fault

as no code is bullet proof, I was wondering how to best prepare to segmentation fault on an apache output filter that does manipulation on the original content sent.

Of course lots of QA is the way to deal with it but in order to prepare to the unplanned I was thinking I should be able to resend the request and send the content without modification before the process exits.

Is this doable at all ?

any examples out there ?